# How to make theme color option and it applied it to all in HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

I want to know how to make that like changing the theme color and it applied in all HTML pages using my phone only. I have 6 colors that it need to have in my web project.[Page 1 is the settings page (with theme color and others are ordinary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK9ET.png)
[CSS styles, it shows of each color themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56O8E.png)

As you see the image above, page1.html is a setting page which have the theme color option is there and the other remaining pages are ordinary (like an article, etc.) If the page 1 (settings page) successfully changed the theme color then it applied to all HTML pages available in web folder.

I want to have a HTML codes for options and save changes button.

I want to expect to having to change the theme color and it applies it to all HTML pages. The change still remain even the browser is closed or the phone is restarted.

For example: if the default theme is blue and change it to yellow, then it stays it to yellow (even the browser is closed or restarted) until the user change the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage.  [Localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)